# Visual Basic stuck with array issue - probably simple solution

Tags: arrays

I have an array I got using `GetSubKeyNames`.

I am trying to write a value to the registry for each profile that is found in the path location for the profiles I obtained as an array.

The code I have below doesn't work. It is to do with the  & `profileNames(index)` & bit in the code I am sure. I am trying to move through the array to create a new path for each array profile name.

```
SoftwareKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software")
Autodesk = SoftwareKey.OpenSubKey("Autodesk")
AutoCAD = Autodesk.OpenSubKey("AutoCAD")
R191 = AutoCAD.OpenSubKey("R19.1")
ACADD001409 = R191.OpenSubKey("ACAD-D001:409")
Profiles = ACADD001409.OpenSubKey("Profiles")


Dim profileNames() As String = Profiles.GetSubKeyNames() 

Dim ProfileLgth As Integer = profileNames.Length

Dim index As Integer = 0
While index <= ProfileLgth
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\" & profileNames(index) & "\Dialogs\Appload\Startup", "Dword", "Value")

index = index + 1
End While
```

Comment: If you are looping through all the elements of the array I would use the bondaries, instead of the while loop I would have For index = lbound(ProfileNames) to ubound(ProfileName) and change the End While to Next (Also delete index - index + 1 and get rid of = 0 after dimming index)

Comment: Which version of Visual Basic are you using?  Please edit your question and add the appropriate version to the tags.

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved the problem using a different method i just learned. Here it is:

```
              For index = LBound(profileNames) To UBound(profileNames)
                    'MsgBox(profileNames(index))
                    Dim ProfileValue2014 As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\" & profileNames(index) & "\Dialogs\Appload\Startup", "NumStartup", Nothing)
                    Dim ProfileValue2014add = Convert.ToInt32(ProfileValue2014) 'Change Appload value to an Integer from a string

                    Dim Number As Integer = ProfileValue2014add + 1 'Add 1 to Appload list
                    Dim NumberStr As String = Convert.ToString(Number) 'Convert Number back to string for registry to not crack the shits


                    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\" & profileNames(index) & "\Dialogs\Appload\Startup", "NumStartup", NumberStr)
                    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\" & profileNames(index) & "\Dialogs\Appload\Startup", NumberStr & "Startup", "C:\Program Files\Shadow Multi Cast\loadmnu.lsp")

                Next index
```

Comment: I wouldn't have a Dim in a loop, I would Dim them up top then set the value in the loop.